# Partial updates in Phoenix and function signature

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to create a partial update method via ajax/json. How should my "update" function look like?

```
def update(conn, %{"a" => a, "b" => b, "c" => c} = params) do
    # ....
end
```

Namely, only one of these parameters is required **at a time**. How can I specify that? Or should instead do this:

```
def update(conn, params) do
    # ....
end
```

check if params contains `a`, `b` or `c`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching to define all possibilities:

```
def update(conn, %{"a" => a} = params) do
  # Do something when you have "a"
end

def update(conn, %{"b" => b} = params) do
  # Do something when you have "b"
end

def update(conn, %{"c" => c} = params) do
  # Do something when you have "c"
end

def update(conn, params) do
  # Handle everything else
end
```